# web audio stream player without Flash

Tags: audio-streaming, internet-radio

I'd like to build a web radio with functions play/pause/stop/change channels with my own GUI. How can I do it without Flash?

thanks
Jul

Answer (score 1):

checkout the [audio](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/video.html#audio) tag in html 5. It won't work with IE though.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but you can include a flash player. Look flajector. It must help you.